# Google Speech Recognition not working in python 3.8.3rc1 even when Pyaudio installed

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I was making an voice assistant(JARVIS) from a youtube video.

The program cannot recognize anything.

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyaudio
def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))
    return said
get_audio()
```

**Before flagging this question as a duplicate please read this:**

I know there are many questions asked on the same topic, but in all of them Pyaudio was not installed.I have installed speech recognition as:

```
pip install speech_recognition
```

And pyaudio using a whl file and installing it in Windows Powershell.
Please help...

When I tried to run this program it gives no exception.

Comment: What is the problem exactly, do you get anything picked up from your microphone? What does "audio" contain? Do you have r.energy_threshold configured

Comment: @eemik I printed audio and got its position on the hard disk...i.e <speech_recognition.AudioData object at 0x00000155000A0490>
So I tried printing it with a parenthesis but it is giving me an exception called 'AudioData' is not callable. And I have not got anything picked from my microphone.
And r.energy_threshold is not configured

Comment: Maybe you could first test it with an audio file rather than capturing from your microphone. Also seems like you have to maybe adjust for ambient noise https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3/

Comment: Have done with making audio files but please guide how to use the microphone and how to configure r.energy_threshold